# Looking for a simple but featured command runner for xfce4 on arch

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, xfce, window-manager

Using [archlinux](/questions/tagged/archlinux) 64 with [xfce4](/questions/tagged/xfce4):

I used `xfce4-appfinder` when I hit <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>, but it lacks history feature :

[image]

I tested gnome `gmrun`, history is handled, but no completion (edit: completion with <kbd>tab</kbd>) (unlike `xfce4-appfinder`).

I know kde5 `krunner`, but there's to much dependencies, and the package `krunner` itself is not what I expect :

```
$  pacman -Si krunner | grep Description
Description              : Framework for providing different actions given a string query
```

If I want to install it for real, I used `pkgfile -s krunner`, telling me to install a bunch of package that I don't want :

```
# pacman -S extra/plasma-workspace
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (31) breeze-5.12.2-1  breeze-icons-5.43.0-1  editorconfig-core-c-0.12.1-3  frameworkintegration-5.43.0-1  kactivitymanagerd-5.12.2-1
              kde-cli-tools-5.12.2-1  kdecoration-5.12.2-1  kdesu-5.43.0-1  kholidays-1:5.43.0-1  kjs-5.43.0-1  kjsembed-5.43.0-1
              kpty-5.43.0-1  krunner-5.43.0-1  kscreenlocker-5.12.2-1  ktexteditor-5.43.0-1  kuiserver-5.12.2-1  kwin-5.12.2-1
              libgit2-1:0.26.0-1  libksysguard-5.12.2-1  libqalculate-2.2.1-2  milou-5.12.2-1  noto-fonts-20171025-2
              plasma-integration-5.12.2-1  qqc2-desktop-style-5.43.0-1  qt5-tools-5.10.1-1  syntax-highlighting-5.43.0-1  ttf-hack-3.002-1
              xcb-util-cursor-0.1.3-1  xorg-xmessage-1.0.4-2  xorg-xsetroot-1.1.1-2  plasma-workspace-5.12.2-1

Total Download Size:    70.32 MiB
Total Installed Size:  246.67 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
```

**Anyone knows how to install krunner alone or another (simple) tool that have both history and auto-completion / auto-suggestion without <kbd>tab</kbd> ?**

**Edit** : tried [albert](https://github.com/albertlauncher), but seems too bloat (require [virtualbox](/questions/tagged/virtualbox) !!!)

Comment: Can't figure out how to use it

Comment: I only have this executable with your package : `/usr/bin/verve-focus` and ran in pseudo-term or by a keyboard shortcut, it just exit 1 (error)

Comment: Open settings manager -> Panel -> Items and add verve command line to the panel.

Comment: Installed `plasma-workspace`... `krunner` is the best command launcher I know

Comment: [screencast](http://sputnick.fr/videos/out_20180301141727.mkv) (no TAB typed)